# Vboxmanage resize HDD but not the real size? (CentOS Guest, Windows Host)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, centos, gparted

[image: Strange]

I have this situation. whereas the actual **is 7.62 GB** then i tried to execute the steps given from here [Geekwebsite.](http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/)  to **make it bigger to 14GB (which is 13.92GB)**

**Everything smoothly working**... until i decided to use GParted Live cd as well to expand the remaining freespace to be used.

Once I finished using **GParted**, no error found. I boot up my Linux (guest). And,... login into it... strange thing happened. **The size seems not changed at all?**

Look : [image: Linux still recognized that i'm having 7GB instead of 14GB]

What the things (steps) i forgot to do?